# Chrome extension redirect stuck on "pending"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect

Edit: This issue was reported to the issuetracker, it seems to be an issue with chromes flash player: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=345160

I was using a very simple chrome extension to redirect requests from one API to another. I'm not very experienced when it comes to javascript or chrome add-ons, but a simple solution posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/284110/redirect-urls-in-chrome) was enough.

After the latest update the redirected request is stuck on "pending" in the dev tools. Some googling suggested that the new url might be blocked by some other add-on, but I could reproduce this error with the latest version on a completely fresh installation.
The redirect still works when requesting the API url directly, but not if it is requested by a flash application on a page for example.

Here is the script "background.js" of the extension to redirect the url:

```
var host = "http://example.com";
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
         return {redirectUrl: host + details.url.match(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+([\S\s]*)/)[1]};
    },
    {
        urls: [
            "*://example.org/api/*"
        ],
        types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
);
```

There are probably better ways to do this, but for me this was easy and good enough.
I could not really find a reason for this behaviour in the latest version, can someone help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: have you got any solution on this?